# `journalctl -f -m` does not interleave remote and local

Tags: systemd, debian-stretch, journald

I currently have a 2-server setup (3 servers in total, one still to be configured for this) with one server using `systemd-journal-remote` (`.socket` & `.service`) to collect all log entries from the other machine, which uploads with `systemd-journal-upload`.

I have installed version 239 via `stretch-backports` on the receiving debian server, simply to make `journalctl -m` work, and pick up `/var/log/journal/remote`

This setup is for redundancy and simplicity of logging, and to have a overview of all events on all servers, but `systemctl -f -m` does not pick up *all* logging origins (local and remote), can this be fixed, or is it via design?

**Edit:**

Upon inspection with a rather non-reoccurring service (`cron`), i finally got entries for both machines, but here I think i find the problem;

```
    {
        ...
        "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": "1539710221237971",
        "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP": "5621984625",
        "_BOOT_ID": "afb0d4143851464184f340c4ace9XXXX",
        "_MACHINE_ID": "59b666a7337442898dc7cc671c0eXXXX",
        "_HOSTNAME": "SERVER_RECEIVE",
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": "1539706141105212",
        "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP": "6030701064304",
        "_BOOT_ID": "afb0d4143851464184f340c4ace9XXXX",
        "_MACHINE_ID": "35ade424e59d4ef18a9986a090f6XXXX",
        "_HOSTNAME": "SERVER_SEND",
        ...
    },
```

`journalctl` seems to sort on `__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP`, is there a reason as to why the remote capturing service seems to iterate on a lower count than the actual `journalctl` count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`journalctl` correctly interleaves the machine entries after a reboot, but with flags `-mf`, it only shows a live feed of all *remote* machines, it does not interleave local and remote.

This is a bug, and I have started an issue [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10426).